# Return distribution with stop loss

Tags: brownian-motion, stop-loss

Assume there is a investment with payoff going like a brownian motion, i.e. $dS=\mu dt+\sigma dW$, for simplicity, setting $\mu= \sigma=1$. At $t=1$, the payoff distribution is $P=Normal(1,1)$. If we set a stop loss at $-1$, meaning we will liquidate our investment whenever its payoff hits $-1$. We can calculate the probability of triggering stop loss, which is

$Prob(SL)=2\int_{\infty}^{-1}{Normal(1,1,x)dx}\approx{}0.05$.

The question is, What's the payoff distribution given the stop loss **isn't** triggered?

I think we need to solve the following differential equation:

$u_t=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 u_{xx}+\mu u_x$

$u(-1,t)=0, u(x,0)=\delta(x)$

Answer (score 3):

The payoff distribution will be the truncated normal distribution. In the general case of truncated from both sides, $a\leq X\leq b$, the density is
$$
f(x;\mu,\sigma,a,b)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{\phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})}{\Phi(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma})}
$$
where $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2}$. In your case, that translates to
\begin{aligned}
f(x;1,1,1,\infty) & =\frac{1}{1}\frac{\phi(\frac{x-1}{1})}{\Phi(\frac{\infty-1}{1})-\Phi(\frac{-1-1}{1})} \\
&=\frac{\phi(x)}{1-\Phi(-2)} \\
&\approx 1.02328\cdot \phi(x).
\end{aligned}
(Writing $\Phi(\infty-1)$ is probably abuse of notation, but you get what I mean.) For more details about the truncated normal distribution, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

Comment: Intuitively, the distribution "grows vertically" (is multiplied by a factor >1) so that the area under it still adds to 1 despite the loss of the tails that were cut off.

Comment: @nbbo2, good point.